# Как сделать проверку на значения которые повторяются в массивах и перемещать значение в ключ?

Tags: php, массивы

Дан массив

```
 Array
    (
        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => source
                [1] => id
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => source
                [1] => path
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [0] => login
                [1] => remember
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [0] => login
                [1] => name
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [0] => login
                [1] => password
            )

        [6] => Array
            (
                [0] => awful
                [1] => layout
            )

        [7] => Array
            (
                [0] => awful
                [1] => layout
                [2] => suit
            )
```

Полученные вот таким вот образом

```
$file_array = parse_ini_file("../file.txt");echo "symbol file_array=".count($file_array);
echo"<table border='6px' border-color='red'><td><pre>ДО Foreach";
print_r($file_array);
echo"</pre>";
$key=array();$mas=array();$value=array();
    foreach ($file_array as $k => $v) {
    $key[]=$k;$value[]=$v;

        }
        for($i=0;$i<count($key);$i++){
        if(strpos($key[$i], '.',true))
        {
             $mas[$i]=explode('.',$key[$i]);
               }
        }   
        echo"<td><pre>MAS(.) ";
        print_r($mas);
            echo"</pre>";
```

Иходный массив

```
ДО ForeachArray
(
[version] => ‘1.3.15’
[source.id] => ‘1’
[source.path] => ‘some/path’
[login.remember] => ‘1’
[login.name] => ‘userName’
[login.password] => ‘password’
[awful.layout] => ‘split’
[awful.layout.suit] => ‘tile’
)
```

Как-чем проверить если разделяется точкой массив то значение до точки вставить в ключ массива а значение после точки вставить в "VALUE"  и если значение до точки повторяется в след массиве то значение след массива после точки записать в предыдущий

т.е к примеру

```
Array
    (
        [source] => Array
            (
                [0] => id
                [1] => path
            )

        [login] => Array
            (
                [0] => remember
                [1] => name

            .................
```

или скажите как вырезать то что до точки и то что после и удалять параметр нового массива если в предыдущем есть схожее значение до точки
пожалуйста

Comment: Вообще ничего не понял. Реквестирую файл оригинал

Comment: @Konstantin Choporov

    ДО ForeachArray
    (
    [version] => ‘1.3.15’
    [source.id] => ‘1’
    [source.path] => ‘some/path’
    [login.remember] => ‘1’
    [login.name] => ‘userName’
    [login.password] => ‘password’
    [awful.layout] => ‘split’
    [awful.layout.suit] => ‘tile’
    )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если честно, то я вообще не понимаю про какие вы точки говорите=) Вы бы привели исходный код вашего файла, который парсите

Попробуйте в функцию добавить аргумент true, чтобы обрабатывать с секциями

```
$file_array = parse_ini_file("../file.txt", true);
```

Comment: @abibock_un
ничего не меняет.

    ДО ForeachArray
    (
    [version] => ‘1.3.15’
    [source.id] => ‘1’
    [source.path] => ‘some/path’
    [login.remember] => ‘1’
    [login.name] => ‘userName’
    [login.password] => ‘password’
    [awful.layout] => ‘split’
    [awful.layout.suit] => ‘tile’
    )